# JS regexp error?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Seems that it is a bug in regexp in JS basing, otherwise I cannot explaine why it matches character

```
'test '.match(/^s(?:e)?|s(?:e)?|c(?:q)?|c(?:q)?$/i);
> ["s"]
```

why does that happen?
The meaning of this regexp is : if you have a keyword like 'se' and you want to match only a part of it(like only s or the whole se) you write something like this.

Duplicates happens when you have multiple keyphrase to a keyword relation.

Comment: `s(?:e)?` matches `s` all by itself. The `?` after the parenthesis means that the preceding subexpression can be absent.

Comment: oh, seems that only this one( ^s(?:e)?| ) works as expected, and all other start counting from any other source.
So it needs to be 'test '.match(/^(s(?:e)?|s(?:e)?|c(?:q)?|c(?:q)?)$/i);

Comment: Yes that would match any string starting with "s" or "c" or "se" or "cq"; it's not clear why you have two copies for each of those.

Comment: its irrelevant for now. For example you could have two phrases that you want to help to complete like :

'Test your workbench' and 'Test your mind'. Both have few of the same keywords. I split those phrases to keywords and generate regexp, so duplicates may occur.

It's not the best decision but it works. Also now I delete duplicates from the original regexp.

Comment: @Nadoedalo No, that's not what it does. Are you misunderstanding what the alternation token `|` do?

Answer (score 0):

You gotta group all the possible alternations, or you'll fall into the trap of alternating between partial fragmented subpatterns, which won't work for you. See this:

```
/^(?:s(?:e)?|s(?:e)?|c(?:q)?|c(?:q)?)$/i
  ^^^                               ^
```

If you don't need an alternation, the anchors or the groups at all, remove them:

```
/se?se?cq?cq?/i
```

In this case it sounds like you just built the wrong regular expression. In such event, you will need:

```
/(?:se|es|cq|qc)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp will match ONE of these four groups and only one.

```
/^s(?:e)?|s(?:e)?|c(?:q)?|c(?:q)?$/i
 ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
```

That is to say:

```
^s OR ^se
OR
s OR se
OR
c OR cq
OR
c$ OR cq$
```

where `^` is the start of the string and `$` is the end.

In this case it is matching exactly the `s` (the first possibility in the second alternation group).

I have no idea what you actually want it to match so can't really advise further but that's why it's matching what it is.